# web.config using an absolute path

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config, windows-server-2016

I need to use a rewrite rule for a url(www.example.org/download.php) to hit another file called download.php, that is not in my root directory, but located in C:/repo/other_directory/test/download.php, however, it is not working. I have to use an absolute path in the rule. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. My code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule placestoswim" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="download.php" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="C:/repo/other_directory/test/download.php" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this will work the url paramter of a rewrite is expecting a URL not a file system path.

If you cant move that location, can you create a virtual directory inside your existing site called `downloads`, and point its web root at your immovable folder `C:/repo/other_directory/test/`? Then in your web.config setup a rewrite to use this newly created path `~/downloads/download.php` as the destination for your rewrite for `~/downloads.php`